# XNA Viewport confusion

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, viewport

I want the game to adapt to the screen resolution, but I want the viewport to always stay the same, so the game basically just resizes itself when running on different PCs. How do I do it?
So, for example, screen resolution is 1920x1080 and the viewport is 640x480. How do I stretch those 640x480 onto 1920x1080? Is that even possible?
If this did not make any sense, I'll try to explain another way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this article: http://www.david-amador.com/2010/03/xna-2d-independent-resolution-rendering/

Comment: thanks! but I actually already solved it by using SetRenderTarget, drawing everything to some renderTarget and then drawing the renderTarget with whatever parameters I want